# What is the specific syntax of @derive module attribute and where is it documented explicitly?

Tags: elixir

I expected it to be documented in [`Module`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html), probably with references to `struct`s, but no joy. Seen it used with a single or a list of arguments. All the variations I could find so far:

- **list of module names** such as
  `@derive [MyProtocol, Another]`

  (e.g., [`Kernel.defstruct/1` macro doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defstruct/1-deriving),
        [line 65 in
  `ProtocolTest` (v1.7.4)](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.4/lib/elixir/test/elixir/protocol_test.exs#L65))
- **module name**  such as
  [`@derive Inspect`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.0-rc.0/lib/elixir/test/elixir/inspect_test.exs#L488)
- **tuple** in the form of
  `@derive {Protocol, key1: :val1, key2: val2}`

  (e.g., [line 550 in `InspectTest` (v1.8.0-rc.0)](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.0-rc.0/lib/elixir/test/elixir/inspect_test.exs#L550),
  [`Phoenix.Param` protocol doc](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html))
- **list of tuples** such as
  `@derive [{Prot1, :options}, {Prot2, key: :val}]`

  (e.g., [line 225 in `ProtocolTest` (v1.7.4)](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.4/lib/elixir/test/elixir/protocol_test.exs#L225))

The only places I found mentions of `@derive`:

- ["Deriving" section](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defstruct/1-deriving) in the documentation of `Kernel.defstruct/1` macro
- New (i.e., v1.8.0-rc.0) ["Deriving" section of `Inspect`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.0-rc.0/lib/elixir/lib/inspect.ex#L57)
- Documentation of [`Protocol.derive/3` macro](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html#derive/3) (added in [#7019](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7019))
  (This was extremely helpful because using the example snippets one can test all the combinations above.)

---

Wasn't sure whether I'm not just overlooking something, therefore didn't open an issue or pull request.

Comment: [Thread on Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/what-is-the-specific-syntax-of-derive-module-attribute-and-where-is-it-documented-explicitly/19128)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/toraritte/b2279da070b32e70552da28e535305eb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation is in `defstruct` there:

> For each protocol in the `@derive` list, Elixir will assert there is an implementation of that protocol for any (regardless if fallback to any is true) and check if the any implementation defines a `__deriving__/3` callback (via `Protocol.derive/3`).

And `Protocol.derive/3`:

> If your implementation passes options or if you are generating custom code based on the struct, you will also need to implement a macro defined as `__deriving__(module, struct, options)` to get the options that were passed.

So in other words, `@derive`:

- Accepts a list of tuples in form `{protocol, options}` where `protocol` is protocol on which will be called `__deriving__/3` and `options` is `term` that will be passed as 3rd argument
- `protocol` (where `protocol` is defined as above - atom describing the protocol module) is the same as `{protocol, []}`
- In case of single derived module you can omit wrapping everything in list and use definition directly

---

So your examples can all be rewritten to "more descriptive" like that:

1. List of module names

   ```
   @derive [MyProtocol, Another]
   ```

   Is the same as

   ```
   @derive [{MyProtocol, []}, {Another, []}]
   ```
2. Module name

   ```
   @derive Inspect
   ```

   Is the same as

   ```
   @derive [Inspect]
   ```

   Which is the same as

   ```
   @derive [{Inspect, []}]
   ```
3. Tuple

   ```
   @derive {Protocol, key1: :val1, key2: val2}
   ```

   Is the same as

   ```
   @derive [{Protocol, [key1: :val1, key2: val2]}]
   ```
4. List of tuples is the "canonical" form

I hope that this clarifies everything a little.

Comment: will you please put a usage. I saw this in a piece of code: `@derive {Inspect, except: [:text]}`  and the comment was `# Sanitize sensitive data when using IO.inspect` what would be usage of `inspect` in respect to `@drive` then?

Comment: It will implement `Inspect` protocol for the given struct that will print all fields except `:text`. All is written in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.html).